# "CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll" ends up in my "bin" folder instead of only in "bin\x86"

Tags: c#, .net, cefsharp, visual-studio-2022

Using CefSharp.WinForms successfully since years, I recently am unable to run my WinForms .NET 4.8 application, because of this runtime error:

> System.BadImageFormatException
>
> Die Datei oder Assembly "CefSharp.Core.Runtime, Version=94.4.50.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138" oder eine
> Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Es wurde versucht, eine Datei
> mit einem falschen Format zu laden.

Translated to English this should read something like:

> System.BadImageFormatException
>
> Could not load file or assembly "CefSharp.Core.Runtime, Version=94.4.50.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138"" or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

This happened literally out of nowhere, after all these years of successfully using CefSharp.

I recently switched to VS 2022 RC, but I'm not sure whether this is the cause of it.

Upon further investigation, I found out that the x86 version of "CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll" ended up both in my "bin" folder, as well as in my "bin\x86" folder.

Since my application also supports x64 and therefore on my system runs as 64-bit, it tries to load the x86 "CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll" from the "bin" folder instead of the "bin\x64" folder.

Both folders "bin\x64" and "bin\x86" contains their respective correct version of "CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll", but in addition there is also the x86 version of "CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll" directly in "bin".

When manually deleting the "CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll" in the bin folder, everything works correctly, again and my application runs correctly.

[`AssemblyResolve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve) is *not* fired, since it is only called for *failed* resolutions, and since "CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll" is present directly in "bin", no failure in terms of assembly resolution occurs.

I've also tried to uninstall and install CefSharp NuGet packages, but still does not hinder the build process from putting "CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll" directly into the "bin" folder.

I do suspect some build script/target of CefSharp to be the cause of this, but unfortunately I'm not that much into MSBuild to understand what to look for and where.

#### My question

How to force CefSharp to *not* put bitness dependent assemblies into "bin" but *only* into "bin\x86" and "bin\x64"?

##### Update 1

I do think something along in "CefSharp.Common.94.4.50\buildTransitive\CefSharp.Common.targets" is responsible for this, but again, I'm not sure where to adjust and what to adjust.

Comment: It's very likely related to VS2022 preview as I've yet to install that version. Msbuild is actually responsible for the extra copy which has to be excluded, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/94/NuGet/CefSharp.Common.targets#L13 is the current target. As a short term workaround you can add a afterbuild  target to your project file. If you can please create an issue on GitHub, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title= don't worry about using the bug report temple, just copy paste what you have here please.

Comment: Done: [#3854](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3854), thanks a lot, @amaitland

Comment: Great, thank you. Will continue the conversation there.